# How to detect mistakes in IRIs in a RDF file?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, iri

I am trying to make a RDF corrector. One of the things I specifically want to correct are IRIs. My question is that, irrespective of the RDF format, is there anything that I can do to correct mistakes in the IRI? I understand there can be multiple number of mistakes, but what are the most generic mistakes that I can fix?

I am using ANTLR to make the corrector. I have extended the BaseErrorListener so that it gives out the errors made in the IRI in particular.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the errors made in the real world depend on the source.  A source may be systematically creating IRIs with spaces in, or have been binary copied between ISO-8859-1 ("latin") and UTF-8 (the correct format) which corrupts the UTF-8. These low level errors can be best fixed with a text editor on the input file (and correct the code generating them).

Try a few sample IRIs at http://www.sparql.org/iri-validator.html, which prints out warnings and errors, and is the same code as the parsers.